# Limit as x approach to infinity of Log.

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

I'm trying to solve this:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty} (x-\ln(1+2e^x))= ?$$

I tried [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) but it didn't get me where I want to...

Any hints?

Comment: Please include your workings when applying L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x-\ln(1+2e^x)=$

$ \ln (e^x) -\ln(1+2e^x)=$

$\log (\dfrac{e^x}{1+2e^x}).$

Set $y:= e^x$, and consider $y \rightarrow \infty$ :

$f(y) := \dfrac{y}{1+2y} = \dfrac{1}{1/y +2}.$

$\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} (\log f(y)) =$

$\log( \lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} f(y)) =$

$=\log(1/2)= -\log 2$.

Used:

1) $\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} f(y) = 1/2;$

2) $\log$ is continuous.

Comment: How x became ln(e^x) ? i mean from first line to the second line?

Comment: Andrew. log (e^x)= x log(e) =x ×1, since log(e)=1. Is this ok?

Comment: OK got it thanks. BUT how is ln(1/2) becomes -ln2?

Comment: Andrew: log (a/b) = log (a) - log (b) (look up log rules).log(1/2) = log( 1) - log (2), and note :log (1)=0.Ok?

Comment: Yes, now its clear thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$x-\ln(1+2e^x)=x-\left[\ln e^x+\ln \left(\frac1{e^x}+2\right)\right]=x-x-\ln \left(\frac1{e^x}+2\right)\to -\ln 2$$

To figure out at first sight the result note that for $x\to +\infty$

- $\ln(1+2e^x)\sim \ln 2e^x=\ln2+\ln e^x=\ln 2 +x$

observe that the latter is not a proof but only a method to guess what the limit could be.

Comment: +1 for advice in last sentence. Often people think that reasoning as a proof.

Comment: @gimusi how did you split the -ln(1+2e^x) to that form?

Comment: @AndrewM use that $\log ab= \log a + \log b$

Answer (score 0):

use that $$\ln(1+2e^x)=\ln\left(e^x\left(\frac{1}{e^x}+2\right)\right)=x+\ln\left(\frac{1}{e^x}+2\right)$$